# Are 'shared drives' available in G Suite legacy edition?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business

I haven't found anything that would suggest otherwise, but in my drive account (that is managed by a G Suite legacy license) I don't see the 'shared drives' option.

Do I need to enable this feature somehow? Or do I need to disable

Answer (score 5):

Tl;Dr: No

From https://support.google.com/a/answer/7212025?hl=en

> ## What are shared drives?
>
> This feature is available with G Suite Enterprise, Enterprise for Education, Drive Enterprise, Business, Education, and Nonprofits edition.